# openvpn causing internal kernel errors (Oops: 7)

Tags: vpn

Have a Pi B Board that has been running Openvpn for over a year that the vpn has suddenly stopped working. It stopped responding and had to reset it, and after restart the vpn would not start.
The following is from syslog

```
08:12:50 pi-torrent ovpn-openvpn[1778]: OpenVPN 2.3.4 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jan 23 2016
08:12:50 pi-torrent ovpn-openvpn[1778]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.08
08:12:50 pi-torrent ovpn-openvpn[1778]: WARNING: file '/etc/openvpn/login.txt' is group or others accessible
08:12:50 pi-torrent systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /run/openvpn/openvpn.pid: Invalid argument
08:12:50 pi-torrent ovpn-openvpn[1780]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
08:12:50 pi-torrent ovpn-openvpn[1780]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]104.200.154.56:1198
08:12:50 pi-torrent systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN connection to openvpn.
08:12:51 pi-torrent ovpn-openvpn[1780]: [4d03c906d490bb20496a51074823ccb6] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]104.200.154.56:1198
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.366015] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address dcfb6f53
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.379757] pgd = d4988000
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.388896] [dcfb6f53] *pgd=1ae2f811, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.401612] Internal error: Oops: 7 [#24] ARM
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.411965] Modules linked in: rpcsec_gss_krb5 cfg80211 rfkill xt_owner iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_gpiomem bcm2835_wdt uio_pdrv_genirq uio ipv6
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.447077] CPU: 0 PID: 1781 Comm: modprobe Tainted: G      D         4.4.38+ #938
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.465861] Hardware name: BCM2708
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.474641] task: da5adf60 ti: d493e000 task.ti: d493e000
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.485464] PC is at strlen+0xc/0x38
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.494249] LR is at load_module+0x818/0x1ef4
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.503665] pc : [<c02eab30>]    lr : [<c007d4b8>]    psr: 60000013
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.503665] sp : d493fe80  ip : d493fe90  fp : d493fe8c
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.524979] r10: 000000b9  r9 : dcf70000  r8 : 00000012
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.534932] r7 : dcf7608e  r6 : 0000002c  r5 : 0000010f  r4 : d493ff44
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.545993] r3 : dcf76eb0  r2 : 00000074  r1 : 00000000  r0 : dcfb6f53
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.556911] Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.568484] Control: 00c5387d  Table: 14988008  DAC: 00000055
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.578600] Process modprobe (pid: 1781, stack limit = 0xd493e188)
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.589165] Stack: (0xd493fe80 to 0xd4940000)
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.597868] fe80: d493ff3c d493fe90 c007d4b8 c02eab30 c07222b0 d493fea0 c01325a4 c012cfb0
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.614572] fea0: 00008ea0 00000000 dcf75a8c dcf78e50 dcf759a0 dcf75a88 7f5a73b0 dcf78e78
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.631687] fec0: dcf70000 00008ea0 00020097 00000000 0b300002 c07222b0 00000001 00000000
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.649102] fee0: 00000000 00000000 00008ea0 00000000 587036dd 00000000 58583cba 00000000
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.667041] ff00: 58703824 2aa684a0 00001000 c02a17e0 00000048 00000000 00000000 7f5a73b0
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.685325] ff20: 0000017b c000f9e8 d493e000 00000000 d493ffa4 d493ff40 c007ed3c c007ccac
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.703967] ff40: 00000002 dcf70000 00008ea0 dcf78838 dcf75c21 dcf76eb0 00000000 00000000
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.723219] ff60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000027 00000028 00000020 0000001a
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.742931] ff80: 00000015 00000000 00000000 4e87a400 00000000 00000000 00000000 d493ffa8
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.763136] ffa0: c000f820 c007ecd4 4e87a400 00000000 00000000 7f5a73b0 00000000 7f5a7ba0
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.783803] ffc0: 4e87a400 00000000 00000000 0000017b 7f5a73b0 00040000 7f6bd530 00000000
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.805154] ffe0: beb7fa30 beb7fa20 7f59c0ac b6f31c40 60000010 00000000 1bffa861 1bffac61
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.826958] [<c02eab30>] (strlen) from [<c007d4b8>] (load_module+0x818/0x1ef4)
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.841204] [<c007d4b8>] (load_module) from [<c007ed3c>] (SyS_finit_module+0x74/0x84)
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.862688] [<c007ed3c>] (SyS_finit_module) from [<c000f820>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x1c)
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.884088] Code: c0598598 e1a0c00d e92dd800 e24cb004 (e5d02000) 
08:12:55 pi-torrent kernel: [  696.897226] ---[ end trace dee54cfe8a4dbad5 ]---
08:12:55 pi-torrent rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Tue     08:13:55 2017 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
08:12:55 pi-torrent ovpn-openvpn[1780]: ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such device (errno=19)
08:12:55 pi-torrent ovpn-openvpn[1780]: Exiting due to fatal error
```

No updates have been applied since it was  originally installed.
I removed the iptables rules that were been done after vpn start, but that does not appear to be the causeof the issue.

Openvpn --version returns 
OpenVPN 2.3.4 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jan 23 2016
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.08

uname -a returns
Linux pi-torrent 4.4.38+ #938 Thu Dec 15 15:17:54 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux